# Is Christianity.SE a OP's Gets it or Community Gets it community?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, voting, accepted-answer

[Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers)

So, I haven't read a ton about it, but it seems like we dropped the ball on polling for this, does anybody care?

We don't have a ton of instances of a top-voted answer surpassing the accepted answer.  I had to dig deep to find one of my accepted answers that didn't have the top votes

[Origin of the (mis)translation "Ten Commandments"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/62576/origin-of-the-mistranslation-ten-commandments/62619#62619)

You'll know things changed when my (accepted) answer with 2 votes goes on the bottom of the pile.

I'm not sure that eternal truths should be voted on or selected by the a single person.  If I had my druthers, we'd adopt an EU style technocracy and only allow vetoes on this site. But the people who had veto power would have to wear cool robes as a sign of their power.

Comment: Added Christianity.SE to [the table in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914/625056).

Comment: "I'm not sure that eternal truths should be voted on..." well, fortunately that isn't happening here. [We can't handle the truth](/questions/3527). We don't (at least in theory) discuss eternal truths.

Comment: This has been added to the Community Team's backlog and we'll update you once someone picks it up and evaluates your request.

Comment: Hey! I've just changed the site setting. The accepted answer is unpinned now.

Comment: Great [just tested it out](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/989/what-is-the-basis-for-saying-christians-and-muslims-worship-the-same-god?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am voting for **unpinning the accepted answer** for these reasons:

1. I have seen cases where new answers turn out to be better, especially for popular questions that have been around for more than 8 years or so.
2. The OP is no longer active for years, and that is why in some cases the accepted answer is not changed to the better answer.
3. The community may be the better judge than the OP especially is the OP is not well-versed in theology.  In this case it makes sense for the higher-voted answer to be placed before the accepted answer.

For validation, we may want to run a SE Data Explorer query to provide us with examples.  I have a feeling someone has already constructed this query, a matter of finding it.

Answer (score 3):

**Is Christianity SE a OP's Gets it or Community Gets it community?**

Personally I am onboard with unpinning an accepted-answer, as long as the community is in favour of doing so.

Great idea.

Comment: There's no case-by-case option here. You have to choose for the entire site including all existing questions - are the accepted answers pinned or not?

Answer (score 2):

I support unpinning accepted answers. The general voting system is enough, and in most cases it won't make a difference anyway. But for those rare times when the question asker picked a weird or problematic answer for their tick, it would be better to just let the votes determine the order.

Answer (score 1):

I would always leave the answer pinned to the top.  The nature of Q&A here has always been asker centered and there's always been a disconnect if not a weird animosity between askers and answerers.  I've always tried hard to be a bit of both.   Of course answerers would want the top answer to bubble up to the top.  But that's just yet another way of saying that the person asking the question is wrong.

I don't expect *this* post will garner many likes, but at least you're hopefully reflecting on whether your pride is telling you that the animus you feel toward the person making seemingly arbitrary button clicks not in your favor is a problem with the system or a problem with yourself.

Citing no evidence, I think I've got one of the worst answer-to-accept ratios of anybody who hasn't been banned from the site several times (I think I've only been banned once) so I should probably like this, but it's yet another way to crap on the user.

The reasoning on the technical sites is rather sound.  Versions change etc... But the Truth doesn't change. Here, there's no real conflict.  There's no reason to treat the accepted answer as anything except the defacto answer,  more scholarly gentlemen and women may one day come along and provide a more robust answer but the first, best answer ought to be considered the top answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the same system as with closing and reopening questions? If an accepted answer gets some reasonable quantity of votes (3,5?) the answer gets unpinned. That way at least more community members are involved in making the decision and the default remains as it should be, with accepted answers honored with top rank.